# Kinetic energy of an electron in synchrotron

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrons, synchrotron-radiation

The question states as follows: An electron is accelerated in a LINAC (LINear Accelerator) so that it's kinetic energy is 1.00 GeV. Then it is transferred to a synchrotron where it's *energy* (didn't specified *kinetic*) then reaches 1.20 GeV. While in the synchrontron, the electron emits synchrotron radiation which is used for research purposes. Find the kinetic energy of the electron in the synchrotron and also the equation of motion for the circular motion of the electron in the synchrotron.

3 Questions.

1. Would it be correct to assume that all of the electron's energy (1.20 GeV) is Kinetic Energy. (By Kinetic Energy, I mean $E=(\gamma -1)mc^2$ where $\gamma = (1-v^2/c^2)^{-1/2} $. ) There are no "some of the energy turns into mass", right?
2. While in the synchrotron, how does the electron gain energy to compensate for the loss through synchrotron radiation?
3. How am I suppose to formulate the equation of motion, not being given the radius of "orbit" and magnetic field strength?

P.S. It's an old scholarship exam question; not exactly homework but still tagged homework anyway.

Comment: #2: Have you Google'd any images of Synchrotrons? #3: Symbols are often better to work with than numbers ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The mass of the electron is 0.5 MeV, so, for most pratical purposes, one can ignore the mass when the energy is at 1.2 GeV, the difference, most of the time, would be about 0.05%, which is usually considered small. If there is mass, not all energy is kinectic energy, you are right about that.

2) Depends on the accelerator design, but it's possible to use RF cavity resonators to do the job:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonator#Cavity_resonators

3) The equation of motion is usually modeled with the lorentz force, at least in a first approximation. The equation of motion doesn't requite the value, you call the magnetic field ${\bf B}$ and write it down with it.

Answer (score 0):

so I hope I can give some advice but first, I have a remark. You should precisely state what kind of synchrotron were are talking about. There are, what I call, "classical" synchrotrons which radiate via bending magnet radiation. The new generation synchrotrons radiate via undulators. So you have to make clear what you mean.

For the bending magnet radiation I can give you a sketch for the equation of moiton:

$\vec{F}=e\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$

$|\vec{F}|=evB\sin{\theta}=evB$

$|\vec{F}|=\gamma m\frac{v^{2}}{R}$

$\gamma m\frac{v^{2}}{R}=evB \rightarrow R=\frac{\gamma mv}{evB}\approx \frac{\gamma mc}{evB} $

That is what I would understand by eqaution of motion. But again, first make clear what kind of synchrotron you are talking about.